# How to consume a WCF secure service with PHP?

Tags: php, wcf, wcf-security

I am trying to consume a secure WCF service with PHP, and I can't figure out the syntax. I thought it would be as simple as following:

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://localhost/service.svc?wsdl', array('userName' => "test", "password" => 'pass'));
```

but instead it raises an exception `An error occurred when verifying security for the message.`
 in PHP, and I get the following from Application Log `MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.`

It seems to raise this error regardless of whether I try to supply credentials or not, so I unless I'm getting the syntax wrong, it's not that.

I've seen a few posts around that also blame the header, but I can't really figure out how to specify one, not to mention what it should be.

It's worth mentioning that I can consume the service successfully, as long as it's unsecured. I can also consume it successfully in any mode with a .NET client.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971493 Does this help?

Comment: No, I need both incoming and outgoing messages to be secure.

Comment: Given that OP accepted an answer that only links to another question I'd assume that this is a possible duplicate of [How to consume a WCF Web Service that uses custom username validation with a PHP page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652227/how-to-consume-a-wcf-web-service-that-uses-custom-username-validation-with-a-php)