# wshttpbinding and custombinding don't work with soapClient PHP

Tags: php, soap, web-config, soap-client, wshttpbinding

I can't do a SoapClient in PHP for connect to a WCF Service with with TransportWithMessageCredential clientCredentialType UserName.
SoapClient says:
 
Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="http://tempuri.org/ISecurityService/GetDocuments"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

This is my code of web.config

```
<bindings>

  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsSecureBinding">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
      messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpsBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service
    name="Middleware.Services.SecurityService"
    behaviorConfiguration="ServiceWithMetaData">
    <endpoint name="wsSecureService"
              address=""
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="wsSecureBinding"
              contract="Middleware.Interfaces.ISecurityService"/>
  </service>
</services>
```

And this is my code in PHP
https://pastebin.com/ctVEKX6w

My code is based in two links:
[How to consume a WCF Web Service that uses custom username validation with a PHP page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652227/how-to-consume-a-wcf-web-service-that-uses-custom-username-validation-with-a-php)

[[Connecting to WS-Security protected Web Service with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953639/connecting-to-ws-security-protected-web-service-with-php][3])

[3]: [Connecting to WS-Security protected Web Service with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953639/connecting-to-ws-security-protected-web-service-with-php) 
Does anyone know how to avoid this?
Thanks in advance,
Regards,

Comment: I could solve it!
The solution to place the wshttpbinding in the following way adding establishSecurityContext="false" in the tag message:

<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsSecureBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>

Comment: Now PHP code should use a header similar to the one generated by SOAP UI

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-BDD22EA7A43AF1DBFB154703695485715">

Comment: <wsse:Username>User</wsse:Username>
   <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
   <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">SdeXhgIvCgK13O6d7vHg4w==</wsse:Nonce>
   <wsu:Created>2019-01-09T12:29:14.857Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
   </wsse:Security>

Comment: <wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/ISecurityService/GetDocuments</wsa:Action>
   <wsa:To>https://localhost/Middleware/services/SecurityService.svc</wsa:To>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetDocuments/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>